# Django - Adding text from dictionary in a static tag

Tags: django

In Django, I have this line in my HTML file which adds an image using the static tag. However, it seems like {{ dictionary.key }} is not working in this case.

```
<img src="{% static 'Image/Portfolio/{{article.slug_title}}/{{article.imageFile}}.jpg' %}">
```

Is there any method to solve this problem or it is possible to like with the absolute route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, just need to move some brackets around:

```
<img src="{% static 'Image/Portfolio/' %}{{article.slug_title}}/{{article.imageFile}}.jpg">
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help. Never thought about that way.